# Automapper "flattening"

Tags: automapper

I am trying to "flatten out" the contents of a source List to fields on the Dest object, as follows:

```
class Source
{
    public IList<TypeX> TypeXs {get; set;}
}

class Dest
{
    public int IdentifierXValue { get; set;}
    public int IdentifierYValue { get; set;}
    public int IdentifierZValue { get; set;}
}

class TypeX
{
   Identifier Identifier {get; set;}
   float Value {get; set;}
}

enum Identifier 
{ 
    X,
    Y,
    Z
}
```

Mapping from source to dest works fine using the below mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>.ForMember( dest => dest.IdentifierXValue, opt =>     opt.MapForm(src => src.TypeXs.First(f => f.Identifier == Identifier.X).Value));
```

How do I achieve the reverse mapping? The "Source" reference will already exist and it will have prepopulated references to TypeXs. I just need to search for a TypeX object whose Identifier matches (say X) and for that object I need to replace the value with the IdentifierXValue in the Dest object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Dest, Source>()
      .ForMember(d => d.TypeXs, opt => opt.Ignore())
      .AfterMap((s, d) =>
                         {
                          d.TypeXs.First(tx => tx.Identifier == Identifier.X).Value = s.IdentifierXValue;
                          d.TypeXs.First(tx => tx.Identifier == Identifier.Y).Value = s.IdentifierYValue;
                          d.TypeXs.First(tx => tx.Identifier == Identifier.Z).Value = s.IdentifierZValue;
                         }
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need a [custom type converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters).  That would probably be the easiest way.